# How Do I make matrix 16 x 16 from String?

Tags: java

I have a  string

```
String word = "FrenciusLeonardusNaibaho";
```

while I'm trying to make matrix like this:

```
char matriks[][] = new char[16][16];
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 16; j++) {
            matriks[i][j] = word.charAt(k);
            k++;
        }
    }
```

I got this error

```
String index out of range: 24
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks..

Comment: you need 16^2 characters in that string to fill all the slots of the matrix.

Comment: Ummmm.... `16 * 16 > 24`. What made you think that this would work?

Comment: beter to start i and j with zero

Comment: Hmmm... I think `char[][] blah` is the more Java-like array declaration.

Comment: Basically you have `24` chars in your word string. your array is `16*16`, So after feeling 24 chars in your array it throws the error. Moreover arrays always starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: Could you please provide a better description/example of your expectations of what you want your Matrix to look like after your code executes?

Answer (score 4):

You are **overflowing** beyond the end of `word` at `word.charAt(k);`. Basically you dont have enough alphabets to fill your matrix.

You can do something like this

```
if(k >= word.length())
   break;
```

Below the inner loop. Or you can init the element to some default value with this condition.

Additionally as others have mentioned, i,j should start at 0, unless you have a good reason to start at 1.

Comment: An alternative might be to just reset K, what do you think of that?

Comment: +1 You should also include that arrays starts from `0` not `1`. OP starting arrays from 1

Comment: @Brandon depends on what OP intends to do. If he is repeating or tiling, reset to 0 if just once then break

Answer (score 1):

```
char matriks[][] = new char[16][16];
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        matriks[i][j] = word.charAt(k%word.length());
        k++;
    }
}
```

So it can go from start to end,then restart.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
if(k >= word.length())
    k = 0;
```

to your inner for loop, this will continue filling the array from the beginning of the word.

Comment: I dont think this will stop index out of range error. Better you modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

'Out of bounds' or 'out of range' occures when you try to read or write in an array, list, string or whatever with a range beyond it's boundary. You can't read a a character at index 8 when your string contains only 7 character. It's not your string's RAM and it would cause RAM corruption like it is happening sometimes in C-arrays.

When you set up your array and your for-loop try to check if you are still in bounds of your string with a size or length function of your container. In special case of string it is `length`.

I think you are trying to split a list of names stored in a string. In such a case it is easier to create a dynamic container, something like list (`http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-list-example/`).

Here I have a little example. For those purposes I prefer a while-loop. In cases I know the length of a list at least at runtime without interpreting data a for-loop is a good choice, but not in this:

```
String names = "Foo Bar";
List<String> seperatedNames = new List<String>();
String name = "";
int i = 0;
while (i < names.length()) {
    if (names.charAt(i) == ' ') { // you can check for upper case char too
        seperatedNames.add(name); // add name to list
        name = ""; // clear name-buffer
        i++; // increment i, else it would produce an infinite loop
    }
    name += names.charAt(i++); // add current char to name-buffer and increment current char
}
```

I hope I could help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

of course, you will get this error surely because the character in your word are only 24 character.

to avoid this your need to check the length of your word and need to break the all looping.

Try this code.

```
char matriks[][] = new char[16][16];
int k = 0;
int lenght = word.length();
outerloop:

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        matriks[i][j] = word.charAt(k);
        k++;
        if(k >= lenght){
            break outerloop;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are filling 16x16 array and iterating the loop 16x16 times but your word size is less than 16x16. So put a check when k becomes equal to the word length then terminate the loop.Change your code like this.

```
char matriks[][] = new char[16][16];
int k = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 16; j++) {
        if(k >=word.length)
            break;
        matriks[i][j] = word.charAt(k);
        k++;
    }
}
```